# How to interleave audio video in ffmpeg library

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, avi

I am using ffmpeg to write an .avi file. I have two streams, one for audio and other for video. fps of video varies from 5 - 15 and samples per second of audio varies from 60 - 80.

I am using av_interleaved_write_frame() to write the file. but it is too time consuming. So i want to replace it with av_write_frame().

But for that, i will have to manage the audio video interleaving in my code. I don't understand what combination i should use to interleave audio video properly.

Can anyone please help Or suggest me some sample code.